# The Source And Refactor menus in Eclipse are missing for XML files

Tags: xml, eclipse, menu, comments

The menus Source and Refactor in the eclipse's menubar are missing.

When i am looking a java file, in the java perspective, they appear, but when i change to an XML in the same perspective the menus disappear.

Can you help me with that? So Much Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a correct behavior, since most actions from mentioned menus cannot be applied to XML. Or do you want some specific menu item?